# Is it possible to display an external site/url within the same Salesforce page as a pop-up?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to open an external site/url as a pop-up within a salesforce page? I dont want to open the page in another tab of browser, or in another tab of salesforce, has to be a pop-up within the same Salesforce page.

I came across Web Tabs which allow you to open external websites within salesforce but in a new tab, I want to open in the same tab as a pop-up.

Any help or leads would be much appreciated. Thanks!